# Issues in custom table view in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am implementing my custom table view controller. The issue I am facing is that when i select a particular cell in my table, the color of the cell does not changes and after i return back to this page, it does not show the selection user made earlier. Aslo, my scrollbar is not getting flashed for the first time. Any clue what is missing in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have put this line somewhere in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Please either remove this or do it like:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

or

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What about scrollbar?

Comment: @Abhinav: what scrollbar, will you ellaborate?

Comment: Once your table view get load... to give user a feel of presence of scrollbar so that he could scroll down in the table, a scrollbar flashes for 1-2 seconds on right side of the screen. This behavior comes with default implementation of table view controller.